# Обособление приложений (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, приложение

Нужна ли запятая перед фамилией в предложении "Военный топограф, Сладков хорошо знал горы Кавказа."?

Answer (score 3):

*Военный топограф Сладков хорошо знал горы Кавказа.*

[**Обособление приложений**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_176) (Грамота.ру)

> Если приложение относится к собственному существительному, оно обособляется только в том случае, когда стоит после него. Например:
>   *Иванов, капитан пограничных войск, служил на Дальнем Востоке* и *Капитан пограничных войск Иванов служил на Дальнем Востоке*.

Если бы предложение выглядело так: *Как военный топограф, Сладков хорошо знал горы Кавказа*, то запятая ставилась бы (почему Сладков хорошо знал горы? — по причине того, что был военным топографом).

Согласен с тем, что выделение возможно (см. ответ Людмилы), и привожу ссылку на правило, но ведь пунктуация в данном случае зависит от намерения автора, контекста, повествования.

[**Обособленные приложения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111) (Розенталь, § 19)

> Приложение, стоящее перед именем собственным, обособляется только в том случае, если имеет добавочное обстоятельственное значение: *Прославленный разведчик, Травкин остался тем же тихим и скромным юношей, каким был при их первой встрече* (Каз.) — ср.: Хотя он был прославленным разведчиком… (с уступительным значением).

Answer (score 1):

Да, нужна, это приложение, имеющее дополнительное обстоятельственное
значение: Сладков хорошо знал горы, потому что был
военным топографом.

*Военный топограф, Сладков хорошо знал горы Кавказа.*